# How to check if user has bought consumable item?

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, mobile, idempotent

First, thanks everyone.

Prerequisite：I am providing **consumable** items in my application.
**product:**

1. List item
2. User purchase the item by iap.
3. before my application received the **updatedTrancactions**(Transaction),Network is disconnected.

So my server don't have data to verify the receipt. the user also can not get the "Virtual currency".

Would anyone tell me how to solve this problem，or give me some tip. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

its the standard client-server problem. In case the connection between client and server is severed (due to timeout or other reasons), common way to do it is to retry the request. But if your API calls are not [Idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) and calling an API multiple times can affect the state of your system that many times then we have to resort to do something more clever. Some options you have -

1. Have a local database. When a purchase happens, then first update the state in you local DB. Late lazily sync the DB from client to server, I hear coredata or sqlite is excellent. User is not aware of this and since DB is local the UI will be extra snappy for the user.
2. Second approach is - in case of a failed HTTP call. You keep retrying till the call succeeds.
3. Incase the API is non-idempotent, then you need to have a concept of a token. i.e. a API call with the same token called multiple times is first checked on the server-side if the initial call was a success only if it was a failure execute again. ex. this is very important in banking solutions. Imagine multiple debits from your bank account due to timeouts and someone programmed to keep retrying!

This is all I am able to think of right now. Give it a spin and tell us what worked for you...